# Jinja 2 block inside macro?

Tags: python, macros, jinja2

I have base template that contains macro like this

```
{%- macro local_vars(d) -%}
{%- block local_vars %}
{% endblock -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

So I would like to override this block in the child template and still use the variable "d" from the base template. I tried this:

```
{%- block local_vars -%}
{{d.out.type}} {{d.component_name}}_out;
{%- endblock -%}
```

, but I get error:

```
UndefinedError: 'd' is undefined.
```

I also tried to create the new variable inside the block in the base template, and access it with {{super}}:

```
base:
{%- macro local_vars(d) -%}
{%- block local_vars %}
    {% set dict = d%}
{% endblock -%}
{%- endmacro -%}

child:
{%- block local_vars -%}
{{super}}
{{dict.out.type}} {{dict.component_name}}_out;
}
{%- endblock -%}
```

, but this doesn't work either. I only get the new error:

```
UndefinedError: 'function object' has no attribute 'out'
```

I haven't used blocks before, so any help would be highly appreciated. 
If there is a way to pass the variable to the block in child template, that would be the most painless solution for me, but I'm opened for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does scoping the block help? [jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope)

Comment: @qwattash Yes it does, thank you! Weird thing is that I already tried that before I asked this question, but for some reason it didn't work. I probably just forgot to save the file before running generation.